# Application cannot be installed in the device / emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing a map based app for android and in the final stage of detecting the current location. But now my app is not working. It can't be installed either in emulator or in the real device. Whenever I am trying, I am getting a message in the console which says:

Application (map.apk) cannot be installed.

This is my logcat:

```
01-14 18:08:20.576: D/dalvikvm(342): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4859 objects / 301296 bytes in 100ms
01-14 18:08:20.916: D/dalvikvm(342): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 10156 objects / 616976 bytes in 96ms
01-14 18:08:21.216: D/dalvikvm(342): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4664 objects / 306384 bytes in 88ms
01-14 18:08:21.576: D/dalvikvm(342): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6137 objects / 374304 bytes in 152ms
01-14 18:08:21.956: D/dalvikvm(342): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8481 objects / 648904 bytes in 98ms
01-14 18:08:22.266: D/dalvikvm(342): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6080 objects / 370008 bytes in 98ms
01-14 18:08:22.407: D/AndroidRuntime(342): Shutting down VM
01-14 18:08:22.407: W/dalvikvm(342): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{g.g.g/g.g.g.GPSLocatorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at g.g.g.GPSLocatorActivity.onCreate(GPSLocatorActivity.java:50)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  ... 11 more
```

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

      mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
      mapView.setTraffic(true);
      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



      List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
      Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
      HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
              (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
              (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

          OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","" );
      itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
      mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
      {
      return false;
      }
```

Comment: What is at GPSLocatorActivity.java:50?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 18:08:22.427: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at g.g.g.GPSLocatorActivity.onCreate(GPSLocatorActivity.java:50)` what's on line 50 of GPSLocatorActivity.onCreate()???

Comment: OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","" );
 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay); - this one is my 50th line.

Comment: can you edit your question and post the `onCreate()` code in it's entirety? currently there's not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: not only is it installed, but it is started, also. the question poorly formulated

Comment: OK. Whatever, I am not much experienced in this field of android. I am a starter. That's why making this much mistakes. Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: there is a NPE somewhere. i suggest running it in debug mode, you'll see exactly what is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be problem caused by your location detector. Try this to know 'location' is null or not

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

      mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
      mapView.setTraffic(true);
      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



      List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
      Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
      HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

       //see here;
      location = getGpsLocation();
      if(location!=null){
          GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
              (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
              (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

          OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","" );
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
          mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
      }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  }

  //see here;
  public Location getGpsLocation()
  {
          Location res = new Location("");
          res.setLatitude(0);
      res.setLongitude(0);

          // res = ; try some code to find you your current location

          return res;
  }
  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
  {
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: This is the error, the app is not catching the current location. BUt the codes are correct na? By geopoint, we are retrieving the current location by fetching latitude and longitude; and then with the help of an overlay, that point is adding into the map. Can you please explain if there is any error in this?

Comment: @thampi joseph This code is ok, but you forgot to call the function that detect your current location.

Comment: GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
(int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6)); This code fetches the lat and lon na?

Comment: @thampijoseph yes but it's cause your error. Because you forgot to call some function to get your current location so location null. I've fixed my post, see how it work